# How to avoid specific folders in recursive for salt files

Tags: saltstack

Need to skip a folder in salt file and have never worked with these before. Have the following folder structure on my system

```
/Test
  /A
  /B
  /C
```

Salt state file shows the instructions as:

```
customownergroup:
  file:
    - directory
    - names:
      - /Test
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
```

I want to apply another permission for directory "C" using following code

```
excludecustomfolder:
  file.directory:
    - name: C
    - user: root
    - group: admin
```

but they are getting overridden from above state. How do i exclude that folder because salt state is not showing any option to omit while recursive application.

Reference used: https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/user-guide/en/latest/topics/states.html